# How to add KeyInfo & X509Data under the Signature in SAML 2.0 using Java

Tags: java, saml, opensaml

I am completely new to SAML, I just build the saml but per requirement I also need to add KeyInfo and x509 certificate nodes including client’s public cert, I have used below code to generate the signature element, but dont know how to add
KeyInfo & X509Data inside signature. needing help on this?

```
BasicX509Credential signingCredential = new BasicX509Credential();
    //Namespace nameSpaceSAML = new Namespace("http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#","ds");
    KeyStore keyStore = getKeyStore( signingKeyStorePath,signingKeyStorePassword);
    PrivateKey privateKey = getPrivateKey(keyStore,signingKeyalias,signingKeyStorePassword );
    signingCredential.setPrivateKey(privateKey);
    signature = (Signature) Configuration.getBuilderFactory().getBuilder(Signature.DEFAULT_ELEMENT_NAME).buildObject(Signature.DEFAULT_ELEMENT_NAME);
    signature.setSigningCredential(signingCredential);
    signature.setSignatureAlgorithm(SignatureConstants.ALGO_ID_SIGNATURE_RSA_SHA1);
    signature.setCanonicalizationAlgorithm(SignatureConstants.ALGO_ID_C14N_EXCL_OMIT_COMMENTS);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want less code, there is a helper class for signatures that does this.

```
X509KeyInfoGeneratorFactory x509Factory = new X509KeyInfoGeneratorFactory();
x509Factory.setEmitEntityCertificate(true);
x509Factory.setEmitEntityCertificateChain(true);
x509Factory.setEmitX509IssuerSerial(true);
x509Factory.setEmitX509SubjectName(true);

Configuration.getGlobalSecurityConfiguration().getKeyInfoGeneratorManager().registerFactory("x509emitingKeyInfoGenerator", x509Factory);

SecurityHelper.prepareSignatureParams(signature, SPCredentials.getCredential(), null,  "x509emitingKeyInfoGenerator");
```

This sets KeyInfo, signing algorithms etc. Use the setEmit methods on the factory to set what should be added to the KeyInfo

For more information, read [my blog post on it](https://blog.samlsecurity.com/2015/07/adding-keyinfo-to-saml-message.html).
I also wrote a [book on OpenSAML](https://blog.samlsecurity.com/a-guide-to-opensamlv3.html) where I explain signing and encryption functions and more in detail.

Comment: Thanks @Stefan, it worked. I am also looking for the below elements to be part of <X509Data>, but could not get any information around it.`<X509IssuerSerial> <X509IssuerName>CN=VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G3, OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)10, OU=VeriSign Trust Network, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US</X509IssuerName> <X509SerialNumber>147750819997667206557338217414016145916</X509SerialNumber> </X509IssuerSerial>` Can you please help me how to add these additional element as well.

Comment: Updated the answer. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

For those seeking for answer, as I figured out the solution to add KayInfo elements along with X509Data as below, and it is working fine...

```
KeyInfo keyInfo=(KeyInfo)Configuration.getBuilderFactory().getBuilder(KeyInfo.DEFAULT_ELEMENT_NAME).buildObject(KeyInfo.DEFAULT_ELEMENT_NAME);
        X509Data data=(X509Data)Configuration.getBuilderFactory().getBuilder(X509Data.DEFAULT_ELEMENT_NAME).buildObject(X509Data.DEFAULT_ELEMENT_NAME);
        X509Certificate cert=(X509Certificate)Configuration.getBuilderFactory().getBuilder(X509Certificate.DEFAULT_ELEMENT_NAME).buildObject(X509Certificate.DEFAULT_ELEMENT_NAME);
        signature.setSigningCredential(signingCredential);
        value=org.apache.xml.security.utils.Base64.encode(signingCredential.getEntityCertificate().getEncoded());
        cert.setValue(value);
        data.getX509Certificates().add(cert);
        keyInfo.getX509Datas().add(data);
        signature.setKeyInfo(keyInfo);
```